Need the bot to search for a valid keyword on a product page and exclude unacceptable keyword values
Need your help to create a bot which does the following on a product page link such as this example
The bot should check for certain keywords, which would be provided in a “Valid words” column on an Excel sheet. For the example-link shared, the keyword we are trying to look up is “Nickel”.
This sheet would also have a column for “Invalid words”. In our example, the invalid word against “Nickel” is “Polished Nickel”. So ideally, if Nickel is part of Polished Nickel on the product page, it should be rejected by the bot. If only Nickel is found and Polished Nickel is not found, it should be accepted.
Finally, if the bot is able to find the valid word and not the invalid word, the bot should print “Successful” in the Excel sheet in a separate column. If the bot is able to find both the valid word and the invalid word, the bot should print “Failure” in the Excel sheet. If the bot is not able to find both the valid and invalid words, the bot should print “Failure” in the Excel sheet.
i have mentioned every thing in the above question
